# Deploy Azure resources using REST API

Tags: c#, .net, rest, azure, azure-devops-rest-api

I need to deploy Azure resources as a part of my .Net code. I found the following reference from a Microsoft documentation page:

```
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/sql/
```

I am new to .Net and don't know how to authorize and deploy the resources from the code. From where can I get the information about how I can start this?

As a sample, I found this for Resource group deployement:

```
PUT https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourcegroups/{resourceGroupName}?api-version=2018-05-01
{
    "location":"sotheast-sa"
}
```

This is a very basic question but I had to post this as I am not aware of this context.

Comment: The question is too broad, what resources you need to deploy? The PUT method that shou displayed is a default http **PUT** request

Comment: @MarkiianBenovskyi I need to deploy a resource group followed by SQL database and ADF within the created resource group

Comment: Have you tried this example: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-manager-quickstart-create-templates-use-the-portal

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to get token to start making Azure REST API calls.

1. You can use Postman to generate token. 
   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/
2. You can use the Azure API Management services from within the Azure Portal 
   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/apimanagement/apimanagementrest/azure-api-management-rest-api-authentication

And the list goes on, but one you have token you can use to do CRUD action against Azure.

Hope this helps.